# How to implement an Iterator<E> iterator method in HashSet class?

Tags: java, iterator, hashset

I need to create this HashSet class and I've done everything except for implement the iterate method, I've tried looking up source code for the built in HashSet but it doesn't function the same way as mine so I'm currently at a loss for how to do it. I'm not exactly familiar with iterators especially for HashSet/HashMap so any suggestions would be helpful, I'm assuming its quite simple.

```
public class HashSet<E> implements Set<E> {
    private final int[] primes = {100663319, 201326611, 402653189,805306457, 1610612741};
    private static final double LOAD_THRESHOLD = 0.75;
    
    LinkedList<E>[] buckets;
    int numEntries;
    
    //Parameters for Multiply-Add-Divide compression
    //hash function = ((hashCode() * a + b) % p) % buckets.length
    int a;
    int b;
    int p;
    
    public HashSet() {
        initSet(16);
    }
    
    private void initSet(int bc) {
        //Init the array
        this.buckets = new LinkedList[bc];
        this.numEntries = 0;
        
        //Init the linked lists (buckets)
        for(int i=0; i < buckets.length; i++)
        {
            buckets[i] = new LinkedList<>();
        }
        
        //Init MAD param
        this.p = primes[(int) (Math.random() * primes.length)];
        this.a = (int)(Math.random() * (p-1) + 1);
        this.b = (int)(Math.random() * p);
    }
    
    private int hashFunction(E e)
    {
        // implements the MAD method of compression
        return (Math.abs(e.hashCode() * a + b) % p) % this.buckets.length;
    }
    
    private int getIndex(E e) {
        return hashFunction(e);
    }
    
    @Override
    public Iterator<E> iterator() {
        
    }

    private void expandIfNeeded() {
        if ((double) numEntries/buckets.length > LOAD_THRESHOLD) {
            // save a reference to old buckets
            LinkedList<E>[] oldBuckets = buckets;
            // set up a new array of buckets (twice as large), reinitialize
            initSet(buckets.length*2);
            // iterate through old buckets, adding each entry to new buckets
            for (LinkedList<E> bucket: oldBuckets) {
                for(E e : bucket)
                {
                    buckets[hashFunction(e)].add(e);
                    numEntries++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean add(E e) {
        expandIfNeeded();
        
        int index = hashFunction(e);
    
        LinkedList<E> bucket = buckets[index];
        for(E elem : bucket)
        {
            if(elem.equals(e))
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        
        // If the key doesn't already exist in the set,
        // put the new entry into its bucket.
        bucket.addFirst(e);
        numEntries++;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean remove(E e) {
        int index = hashFunction(e);
        
        LinkedList<E> bucket = buckets[index];
        for(E elem : bucket)
        {
            if(elem.equals(e))
            {
                bucket.remove(e);
                numEntries--;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean contains(E e) {
        int index = hashFunction(e);
        
        LinkedList<E> bucket = buckets[index];
        for(E elem : bucket)
        {
            if(elem.equals(e))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void addAll(Set<E> T) {
        Iterator<E> itr = T.iterator();
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            this.add(itr.next());
            numEntries++;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void retainAll(Set<E> T) {
        Iterator<E> itr = this.iterator();
        E currentVal = null;
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            currentVal = itr.next();
            if (!T.contains(currentVal)) {
                this.remove(currentVal);
                numEntries--;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void removeAll(Set<E> T) {
        Iterator<E> itr = T.iterator();
        E currentVal = null;
        while(itr.hasNext()) {
            currentVal = itr.next();
            if (this.contains(currentVal)) {
                this.remove(currentVal);
                numEntries--;
            }
        }
    }
    
    public String toString()
    {
        String r = "";
        int largestBucket = 0;
        
        for(int i=0; i < buckets.length; i++)
        {
            if(this.buckets[i].size() > largestBucket)
            {
                largestBucket = this.buckets[i].size();
            }
            r += "Bucket " + i + "( " + this.buckets[i].size() + " ) - ";
            for(E e : this.buckets[i])
            {
                r += e + " ";
            }
            r += "\n";
        }
        r += "\nNumber of Entries: " + this.numEntries + "\nLargest Bucket: " + largestBucket + "\nLambda = " + (double)this.numEntries/buckets.length;
        
        return r;

    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you recreating [`java.util.HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)?

Comment: To implement that, we'd need to know about that `LinkedList` and its methods. Is it from `java.util`?

Comment: Yes the ArrayList is java.util, and I am creating a HashSet because my teacher is having us implement and understand data structures

Comment: You need to create a class which implements `Iterator` and return an instance of it. You'll need to implement the `hasNext` and `next` methods, so the class will need to contains some mutable state which lets it remember where it is up to in the set.